# What are the most important programming languages to know for concepts?

Tags: programming-languages

In your opinion, what are the most important languages for a programmer to know? I'm talking about **concepts**, not about how practical the language is.

List the languages and a reason. For example, Lisp for functional programming, JavaScript for prototype-based OOP, etc.

Comment: Poor question, almost any language can teach something and the importance is weighted by personal experience and domain.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

**Must know**:

1) C (system programming, understanding of machine architecture)

2) Perl or Python or Ruby (practical day-to-day tasks)

3) Java or C# or C++ (OOP, and quite important to get a job these days)

**Really important:**

1) Haskell or ML (functional programming; changes the way you think)

2) Lisp or Scheme (power of macros)

**Nice additionals:**

1) Forth (very low-level, explicit stack operation + joy to write your own interpreter)

2) Assembly languages (know how your CPU works)

3) Erlang (parallel processing)

4) Prolog (logic programming)

5) Smalltalk (true OOP and true interactive developent)

Comment: COBOL, so you never repeat the same mistakes :-)

Comment: @Pax - What's worse, COBOL or APL?

Comment: Well, COBOL is at least readable (and we still use it on the mainframes). Is anyone still using APL?

Comment: The last I heard of APL being used was in investment banks.

Comment: Forth, just as good for macros as Lisp or Scheme.

Comment: I am learning APL right now.  The airline industry uses it and I get to convert it to C#.

Comment: C - not only system programming but to understand how memory is handled (pointers, heap, stack, method frame on stack and so on), this is important to understand other high level languages that don't have pointers and allocate objects on heap (Java?), as well as those that have pointers and return objects (Objective-C)

Comment: If you want to know how the machine architecture works, you learn assembly language, it's simpler than C too. You can't teach an (albeit broken) abstraction without ever seeing a concrete case of it. @Chris Lutz: APL is a powerful language, COBOL is not.

Comment: Will you add JavaScript along with Python/ruby ?

Answer (score 29):

- The **assembly languages** of as many chips as you can learn for low-level knowledge.
- **C** to learn more practical knowledge of low-level workings, since almost all languages are implemented in C.
- **C++** for object-oriented programming on top of the low-level goodness of C.
- **Pascal** to learn how to work with strong typing.
- **Java** to see how you can shield yourself from low-level concerns.
- **Perl** to learn regular expressions, weak/dynamic typing, and other good things.
- **Python** to see strong/dynamic/duck typing.
- **Ruby** to see how object-orientedness works on top of Perl-esque weak/dynamic typing.
- **Common Lisp** for that functional enlightenment.
- **Scheme** for the emphasis on recursion.
- **Emacs Lisp** so you can extend Emacs.
- **Haskell** to see pure functional programming done right.
- **APL** so you learn how *not* to write code.
- **COBOL** so you can make mad money maintaining legacy code.
- **Erlang** to really learn about concurrency. (Thanks to Pete Kirkham for correcting me.)
- **Scala** for functional programming on the JVM.
- **Clojure** for a Lisp-like functional language on the JVM.
- **Prolog** to understand logic programming.
- **D** so you can see why all the D fanatics are always so pro-D.
- **C#** so you can program for .NET (and Mono).
- **F#** so you can do functional programming on .NET.
- **Forth** for stack-based languages.
- **PHP** so you can see how *not* to create a language. (Just kidding. Learn PHP beacause it's really useful for web development.)
- **JavaScript** because it's basically *the* language for client-side web scripting.
- **bash** for a good, general-purpose scripting language.
- **Visual Basic** so you can read the code your boss wrote. =)
- **INTERCAL** for "fun."
- **brainfuck** so you can torture your friends.
- **LOLCODE** so you can convince them to still be your friends after you subject them to brainfuck.

...And so on.

Comment: Erlang is about concurrency - for the first 20 years it didn't support SMP ( threads and parallelism ) at all!

Comment: Forgive me. I'm not familiar with the differences between different concurrency paradigms.

Comment: Realtime language counts? like Ada ?

Comment: http://processing.org/ 
"Processing is an open source programming language and environment for people who want to program images, animation, and interactions."

Comment: ActionScript? for working in a animation timeline environment.

Comment: Visual Basic also helps in learning VBA.

Comment: I can't list everything - this list would get huge, and I'd spend the rest of my life maintaining it. That said, Ada probably deserves a mention. I don't know about ActionScript, and I'm not a huge fan of Processing (although I've already mentioned C#, VB.NET, and Python).

Comment: I'm surprised Smalltalk hasn't been mentioned. It deserves more mention than, say, Emacs Lisp and PHP. :)

Comment: @musicfreak - I agree, but I don't know enough about the language to give it a one-liner description of why it deserves mention. I did try, but I couldn't find a concise way to point out its differences from other major OO languages. (This is probably just because I'm not too big on OO myself.)

Comment: "Emacs Lisp so you can extend Emacs.", so you assume that extending Emacs is 'a concept'? I would say that it is a very specific task. I would understand if concept was to extend editor (?) - but would you need a specific language for that?

Comment: @stefanB - I just started listing everything I could think of. I'll edit again if I can come up with enough good languages and good reasons to add. Currently only have Smalltalk, Ada and maybe ActionScript.

Answer (score 10):

C for understanding how the most other language(-implementations) and operation systems are implemented

Comment: Some have big trouble understanding why it is not good to return reference to private variable in Java class, it's hard to grasp the concept without understanding C, memory management, stack, heap, pointers, references (address) and so on

Comment: @stefanB: I don't see how throwing in a language based around undefined semantics and types that are magically dereferenced and/or placed on the stack/heap for whatever reason will help **anyone** learn what a reference is... I grasped references in a few minutes when I didn't know anything about computers and came across VB, I wasn't even aware of the existence of C or machine code...

Answer (score 6):

I think the three languages that best combine practicality and coverage of programming concepts would be

- C
- Python
- Javascript

From these languages you can learn low-level system programming, pointers and memory management, static typing, dynamic typing, high-level scripting, event-driven programming, OO programming, functional programming.

Obviously you're not going to get as pure an intro to functional programming as you would with, say, Haskell, but you can learn a lot of the concepts in Python and (especially) Javascript.

Answer (score 5):

It is not the languages rather the paradigms you should know:

- procedural (like C, Pascal)
- object-oriented (like Java, C++, Smalltalk)
- functional (like Lisp, ML, Scala)

If you understood one of these paradigms in one language, it is easy to learn another language in the same paradigm. And there are even more fields specially supported by languages that are important to understand:

- parallelism (in Erlang or Scala)
- declarative templates (e.g. in C++ or Prolog)
- dynamic languages (e.g. JavaScript)

At at last you should always know what goes on under the hoods, so you better have a look at assembler.

Answer (score 3):

I would say:

- C or Assembler to understand how the processor work.
- Smalltalk (or C#, Java, Python, Ruby, etc) to understand object oriented programming.
- Lisp (any Lisp, Scheme, Common Lisp, Clojure) to understand high level programming, meta programming (macros), etc.
- Haskell to understand type inference and other functional concepts.

If you are into distributed systems, I'll consider learning Erlang too. Those are the language I recommend learning, even if only superficial, only for the sake of learning even if you never use them to write a real application.

Answer (score 3):

Its best to know a variety. This gives you a better overall perspective of the art of programming, plus, you get to choose the best tool for the job.

My current list would be:-

- C - programming close to the machine.
- Python - programmers nirvana.
- Perl - for when s**t happens.
- Java - cause it will keep you in work.
- C# - cause it will keep you in work.
- lisp, scheme or something functional to get your brain out of a rut.
- SQL - for managing large data sets.
- JCL, COBOL, VAX DCL, CShell VB - just to remind you how bad things could be!

Answer (score 2):

A good **short list**:

1. C for the machine concepts
2. Haskell for functional programming
3. Smalltalk (or maybe Ruby or Simula-67) for object-oriented programming
4. Prolog for logic programming
5. Icon for backtracking and mind-blowing string processing
6. Bourne shell for Unix scripting

Might also include

7. Scheme for macros
8. Awk or Perl or ... for regular expressions
9. FORTH for tiny bootstrapping postfix wonderfulness :-)

Answer (score 1):

For concepts, I would choose assembler and Java.

The first because you should know in intimate detail how machines work.

The second because you should understand how to shield yourself from the intimate details of the way machines work :-). By that I mean a language with a rich set of data structures at hand (so really Java could be Python, C++ with Boost and so on).

Answer (score 1):

Well. I'd say learn C and javascript. They are most widely used languages.

You might want to learn Java/some .Net language and/or python/ruby: they're more convenient, tho.

This have the advantage that all those languages are reasonably well designed.
For example, don't learn PHP or C++ because they're a mess. They're used widely, you might want to learn them one day, but they can seriously mess with your mind.

Answer (score 1):

[Limbo](http://www.vitanuova.com/inferno/papers/limbo.html) - a programming language with concurrency and channels, what C should have evolved into. ( see also [D](http://www.digitalmars.com/d/), another C successor )

No-one else seems to be mentioning any declarative languages, so here are a few:

[Prolog](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prolog) - a declarative language for logic programming

[Modelica](http://www.modelica.org/) - a declarative OO language for modelling systems.

[XSLT](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt) - a declarative language for transforming XML.

For parallelism, you don't get much wider than [shader language](http://www.opengl.org/documentation/glsl/), and the related [OpenCL](http://www.khronos.org/opencl/) - typically 512 processors in parallel on a high-end desktop, rather than Erlang's 4 processors in parallel ( though with many scheduled processes ).

Answer (score 1):

This is a good question. I know a lot of people, myself included, get stuck in a rut where we are just churning out code like one would churn out burgers at a McDonald's. Coding becomes too mechanical—we understand how to get things done, but often times we forget why these things get done behind the scenes.

In my world it's been C++/C/ObjectiveC that have taught me the most, even though I write C# every day at work.

For the most part, learning C++ has helped me learn about memory management and how the various objects are stored in memory, etc.—the actual science of programming. What really opened my eyes was the Programming Paradigms class offered at Standford that you can get off of iTunes and I think YouTube.

Answer (score 0):

You already mentioned two, here are a few more:

- Java: Java is a good example of OOP 'cause you HAVE to use oop, and it's designed from the ground up to be an OOP language.
- BASIC: Although obsolete, it's a good example of procedural languages and it has a very easy syntax.

Comment: C'mon guys, leave a comment if you downvote. How are people meant to learn or adjust their answers?

Comment: Actually Eiffel would be the better language to pick up OOP, imho.

Comment: I haven't tried Eiffel but I know that Java is really helpful, I saw a lot of the OOP concepts in action just by writing a hello world program.

Comment: I assume you mean Structured BASIC. I wouldn't call the BASIC I learned "procedural."

Answer (score 0):

Pseudocode for reading/writing documentation. :p

I think knowing C/C++ or any other low level language will help you with understanding the impacts of how managed/script languages works helps. Such as pointers will demystify variable references.

Comment: But references are not pointers (they don't even need to be addresses) :-)

Answer (score 0):

For web programming: PHP, ANSI-SQL, javascript.

Some people may argue that HTML and CSS are not programming languages. But they are esential for web app development.

---

For Desktop app development, C++ with the Qt Framework. Qt gives C++ the additional "cross-platform" fizz.

Comment: Please reread my question; I'm asking about *concepts*, not about practical languages.

Comment: HTML and CSS are not programming languages, and there is no "arguing" about it. If it's not turing complete, it's not a programming language.

Comment: Hmm, point taken. And you've justified your nick too!

Answer (score 0):

Pascal or Basic for start and to master basics of procedural programming.

At school we learned Haskel for functional programming.

And then one should try assembler or C for getting deep and Java for OOP.

A have no arguments for this - that's only my taste and what I tried.

Comment: Hello, it's 2009 o'clock, why learn pascal or basic when we've got python!?

Comment: "2009 o'clock" - ha ha. Good one *snort*.

Comment: My copy of Code Complete has code samples in BASIC and Pascal, yet the concepts it conveys are far from outdated :-)

Comment: once again for those with 2009 o'clock ;) - I have no arguments for this - that's only what I tried :)

Comment: @Johannes:  My copy of Elements of Programming Style has its code samples in FORTRAN 66 and PL/I, but its concepts are far from outdated either.

Answer (score 0):

I would sat C/C++ cause it sets allot of basics for allot of other languages used around the world.

Personally I learned Java/JavaScript->VB(short course fortunately)->C#->C++, with a pinch of PHP and Perl on top of it all. Best part of that line was C# and then moving behind the scene in C++.

Answer (score 0):

Look for a set of *different* programming languages:

- C++ / C# / Java etc.
- C / Assembler
- Python, Ruby, Lua, Perl etc.
- sh, awk, sed, regular expressions
- Prolog (or similar)
- Haskell / Lisp etc.

It doesn't really matter which ones you choose, but that you choose one from each "category".

Answer (score 0):

You should know a scripting language so that you can prototype your applications faster.

Maybe python/ruby/perl . Groovy is also an alternative if you're a Java guy that likes his java libs.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to **understand** computers and the underlying hardware, **C** is the single most important language, commonly said to be the [lingua franca](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lingua_franca) of computers. The Stackoverflow podcast tends to cover this at [least](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/podcast-51/) [once](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/podcast-48/) a [week](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/02/podcast-42/).

There seem to be enough answers on this, so I'll just leave it at that.

Answer (score 0):

Alot is already mentioned but I would definitely add C++ (already done) for the following reason:

**C++** for **learning how to use pointers** and get the main idea about them.

Although there is the discussion if c++ is still the 'better' language (all depends on what you want to make really) it never hurts to understand pointers, just in case you do need them ever.

Comment: Surely Pascal/Delphi have a better way to teach it. Is not only more clear implementation, you don't need to have that syntax garbage of C/C++ all around obstructing enlighment ;)

Answer (score 0):

Having a scan through the answers so far I'm surprised I've not seen any mention of actionscript.

I think if you learn some C/C++, then some Java then that should prepare you for pretty much all of the decent languages out there.
I prefer to see my code in action and I find Actionscript 3 (not 2 or 1) along with Flex (which is MXML) great for quickly demoing visual concepts.

So C & Java helps to learn the syntax of the majority of languages.
Actionscript 3 (very similar to java syntax) & MXML for being able to express you code visually very quickly.

Answer (score 0):

C - low level system programming plus to understand generic concepts about how memory is handled, stack, stack frame, heap and so on. These are helpful for understanding higher level languages

C++ - mainly std library (separation of generic algorithms and containers), templates, namespaces, but OO concepts as well. Templates meta programming will give you completely different perspective on writing software, this is compile time execution versus run time execution. Templates inheritance (static vs dynamic polymorphism).

Python - dynamic type system, list comprehension - functional programming (?), no memory management for developer, spaces for indentation

Objective-C - message dispatching (can dispatch to nil), dynamic type system (static as well), late binding, OO concepts

Answer (score 0):

It may sound crazy, but I first learned to program writing VBScript macros for windows. I used a template, which is available here http://vbscript-macro-template.blogspot.com/ and I just added to it and also tried to understand everything that it did. Now, several years later I am writing my own desktop and database applications.

Answer (score -1):

You should start from C and go through C++, Java and the goto WinForms,
Then better goto .NET

Comment: What if he's a mac guy? What if he wants web development?

Comment: He should specify what he need.

Comment: Either way, programming concepts should transcend specific operating systems and development environments.

Comment: I looked up WinForms. It has something to do with Real Estate. You have me baffled.